# How to get checked categories in (back-end) widget form

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, widget

i'm building a wordpress widget which allow the user to choose from a list of categories, which categories to display in the sidebar (along with it's description and a custom icon).
I'm having trouble with getting only the checked categories.

here is my code:

```
    $categories = get_categories();


    $defaults = array( 'title' => 'Categories Title','categories' => $categories);

    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );

    if (isset($instance['title'])) {
        $title = $instance['title'];
    }else {
        $title = __('New title', 'text_domain');
    }

    if (isset($instance['categories'])){
        $categories_list = $instance[ 'categories' ];
    }else {
        $categories_list = __( 'put here array', 'text_domain');
    }

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" 
                name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" 
                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'categories' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Categories List:' ); ?></label> 
        <?php foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
            <p>
                <input  type="checkbox" 
                        id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'categories' ); ?>" 
                        name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'categories' ); ?>" 
                        value="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>" 
                />
                <label>
                    <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
                </label>
            </p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </p>

    <?php 
}
```